# Why is data from Heroku-Postgres not displayed once I pushed to Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, express, heroku, handlebars.js

I have an Express js project pushed to Heroku and it is talking to Heroku Postgres add-on.
In this app, I have form that is collecting user info, department info and stores them in postgres.
I am using express handlebars to display them on the client side.

Everything works great in the local environment. I can see Data stored and displayed via localhost.

However, the data stored in Heroku Postgres is not displayed in Heroku environment.

I have debugged the following and a few things are clear.

1. Using DataGrip I connected to heroku postgres and data is properly stored. and I can see them.
2. Instead of handlebars, I returned json and it returns correctly. so the app in heroku environment is retrieving data from postgres correctly and is able to return in json format.
3. Instead of displaying them in a table format, I just printed them as below.

   ```
   {{#each data}}
     <h1>
       {{this}}
     </h1>

     <h3>
       {{this.departmentId}}
     </h3>
   {{/each}}
   ```

   And from the above code, it shows, `[object SequelizeInstance:Department]`. But `<h3>` tag is absolute empty.

Again, everything works in the local environment, so I don't think that `departmentId` is wrong. because it is defined in the model and used in the local environment.

```
var Department = sequelize.define(
  "Department",
  {
    departmentId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    departmentName: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  {
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
  }
);
```

After the above three debugging, I am lost and not sure where to restart.

Can someone point out the problem in my code?
Let me know if any of the code needs to be posted.

Thank you in advance.